Place "Opus" instead of Instrument Name?
I'm trying to place the opus to the left of a Staff (which is normally the place of the instrument name), like this:

Is there a proper way to place opus in replacement of instrumentName? Something like what we do in \paper{ scoreTitleMarkup = \markup ... }.
The only way I know for now is to set a FAKE instrument name, which seems to be a bad way of layout hacking:
\version "2.24.3"

melody = \relative c'{  c4 d e f   }

\score {
  \new Staff \with{
    instrumentName = "No.1" % IT SHOULD BE OPUS INSTEAD!
  }
  \melody
}

\score {
  \new Staff \with{
    instrumentName = "No.2" % IT SHOULD BE OPUS INSTEAD!
  }
  \melody
}

I tried with the \context setting but it didn't work:
\version "2.24.3"

\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff \with{
      instrumentName = \markup \fromproperty #'header:opus
      % NOT WORKING!
    }
  }
}

melody = \relative c'{  c4 d e f   }

\score {
  \header {
    opus = "No.xxx"
  }
  \new Staff {
    \melody
  }
}


I've always used the first code block when I wanted the opus number in the instrument name.  Even if you could get the second code block working, how would you stop the printing of the opus in its regular place?

The second block was mimicking \paper like this:
  scoreTitleMarkup = \markup {
    \right-column {
      \fill-line{        \fromproperty #'header:title      }
      \line{        \fromproperty #'header:composer      }
      \line{        \fromproperty #'header:poet      }
      \line{        \fromproperty #'header:arranger      }
    }
  }

In this way I can relocate Poet to the right column. I tried to do the same for Opus, but it didn't work obviously.

But how are you keeping the actual header values from printing?
